# How to pick the Base DN for LDAP?

Tags: ldap

I'm setting up an LDAP (LLDAP, for same-sign on) and I understand every directory needs a Base DN. I understand the Base DN works like a namespace containing all the entries of this directory. It seems that changing the Base DN of a running LDAP setup may not be trivial.

So how should I pick the Base DN? Is it completely arbitrary or could certain requirements emerge at some point?

Should it be a domain that I own or a reserved/Private DNS Namespace otherwise?
Should it have two dc-components?

A requirement I've found out about so far is that for some applications, the Base DN may not be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`how should I pick the Base DN?`

I would start with the organization name, and select an adaptation that is intuitive, short, and non-controversial. Then add a sub location so that you are not hosting this particular directory at the root of the domain.

For example, Acme Missile Supply could be "DC=Identity,DC=AcmeRockets,DC=com".

`Should it be a domain that I own?`

Yes. Don't use a domain that is or could be owned by another entity. This would make your organization vulnerable to name lookup hijacking, and the inability to obtain trusted certificates using the name.

`Should it be a private DNS Namespace?`

No. Private names are also subject to the same hijacking, and the inability to obtain trusted certificates using the name.

`Should it have two dc components?`

No. Typically three or more due to you do not want to have a directory distinguished name at the same level as the DNS domain as that usually results in internal and external name conflicts that have messy and unsupported workarounds.

`A requirement I've found out about so far is that for some applications, the Base DN may not be empty.`

That is usually the case for any application. All directories have a structure and a name space. I've never seen one that does not, nor is there a need to.